# How to upload 1 file at a time with multiple selection using blueimp jquery-file-upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp's jquery-file-upload to upload mulitple photos

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I've created a multiple selection input box and setup the upload script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#upload_files").fileupload({
        autoUpload: true,
        dataType: "json",
        singleFileUploads: true,
        sequentialUploads: false,
        url: "/photos/my_upload_script",
        add: function (e, data) {

            data.submit();

        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $("#version_progress_bar .progress-bar").css("width",progress + "%");
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            if(data.result.status == "success"){
                alert('well done');
            }
            else {
                alert("it's gone pete tong!");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem I have, is my historic naming convention for uploaded photos. I'm restricted in that I must use PHP's time() function. This becomes a problem when more than one photo's upload is triggered within the same second.

So, is there a way I can get jquery-file-upload to upload each photo one-by-one but still allow multiple selections in hopes that this will prevent photos uploading within the same second?

Comment: Use php microtime() function instead xD

Comment: @Hackerman Wish I could, but unfortunately I can't due to the restrictions of the naming conventions in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it within the script. So, instead, I put a 1 second sleep on my ajax script.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way I can get jquery-file-upload to upload each photo one-by-one but still allow multiple selections

Yes.  You already have the option in your code that decides this behavior:

```
sequentialUploads: false,
```

Change that to true and you upload sequentially, one after another..